# c++ thread sleep without freezing current thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, sleep

I have writing an application an I need to sleep new thread without stopping executing of current one.

Some code from application:

```
PlaySound(L"sounds\\started.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
thread photos(makeScreens);
photos.join();
CONSOLE_Print("Some testing string");
```

And function that should work asynchronous:

```
void makeScreens(){
    CONSOLE_Print("Make Screens entered");
    srand (time(NULL));
    CONSOLE_Print("Sleeping 30s");
    Sleep(30000);
    CONSOLE_Print("Wake up");
    long int delay;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ //loop for max screens=5
        delay=rand() % 600000 + 60000; //random a delay beetween sreens from 1 to 10 minutes
        CONSOLE_Print("Sleeping "+delay/1000);
        Sleep(delay); //sleep 
        CONSOLE_Print("Wake up and make screen");
        gdiscreen(i); //take a screen
    }
}
```

So I want to run makescreens() without stopping current execution of app. My output should be like this:

```
Some testing string
Make Screens entered
Sleeping 30s
Wake up
Sleeping xxxx
Wake up and make screen
```

How to fix it? Is there any other way instead of using sleep? I'm nawbie in c++.

Comment: The point about `Sleep` is to freeze the current thread, so your question doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `photos.join();`.

This will make your main thread wait until the photo thread is finished.

Comment: So how to call it without waiting untill it ends?

Comment: try photos.detach(); But you have to make sure the main thread runs until your photo thread finished, otherwise it will be killed before it is finalized.

Answer (score 0):

join means that the main thread (which launched new thread) waits for launched thread to finish before proceeding.  So the ordering below should meet your printing order requirement.

```
PlaySound(L"sounds\\started.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
CONSOLE_Print("Some testing string");
thread photos(makeScreens);
photos.join();
CONSOLE_Print("new thread has now finished running");
```